# Is Celery really async?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, django-celery, django-channels

I am codig a realtime game using celery and django-channels.

I have a task that works like a timer and if this timer reaches to zero, once the task was activated, a group_send() is called. From what I see, celery tasks are async but we can't await functions inside tasks.. this makes me a little bit confused.. here is the code:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def count_down(channel_name):
    set_random_game_result(channel_name)
    room = process_game_result(channel_name, revoke=False)
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        channel_name,
        {
            "type": "game_room_info",
            "room": room
        }
    )
```

from the docs:

> By default the send(), group_send(), group_add() and other functions are async functions, meaning you have to await them. If you need to call them from synchronous code, you’ll need to use the handy asgiref.sync.async_to_sync wrapper

So if celery is async, why can't I use the group_send without using the async_to_sync util?

Another thing is about querying.. From the docs:

> If you are writing asynchronous code, however, you will need to call database methods in a safe, synchronous context, using database_sync_to_async.

`database_sync_to_async` actually doesn't work inside the task function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are talking about is something that is done by design, for a good reason. It is also [well-documented](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks), and can be solved easily with appropriate Canvas.

Also... Do not get confused with terminology... Celery *is* asynchronous, but it is not "Python async" as it predates the Python's asyncio... Maybe Celery 5 will get its async parts replaced/refactored to use Python 3+ asyncio and related.